# Default discord emojis in embeds discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I've seen a bunch of stackoverflow questions about how to add custom emojis to embeds, but is there any way you can add default emojis to embeds? Like default discord emojis like :wave:, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default emojis can bu use as `<:name:id>`